# can you block messages from web workers until you are ready to receive them?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-worker

What i want to be able to do is in effect is check for messages from my web workers at a set point. so at the moment I have it set up so i tell my web workers to go ahead and get on with some complex calculations in the background and then my main frame gets on with some stuff too and then when the web workers are done they interrupt the main frame to do their callback function and it usually does this at a non ideal time effecting performance. So is there a way to kind of queue the callbacks and then run them when main frame says it's ok to do so...?

The only option around this i can see at the moment is to set up an extra worker where the other workers post their results to using 'MessageChannel' when they are done which can then be checked by the main frame on it's own terms!

thanks...

---

**Update**

after messing around with this for a while, i've realised what i thought was my problem is not actually my problem! what's actually happening is that when my web worker's finish this actually slows down my code... and given that i'm running an animation in the main frame this is seen as a stutter when each worker finishes! If I keep the worker going in the background with random tasks then this doesn't happen :-/ Very confusing??

Why would this happen? It's not as if I'm calling anything when the script finishes...

---

**update 2**

after a ridiculous amount of searching and playing around it turns out that this is only an issue when chrome (62) devtools is open!

Comment: What is the issue with using `message` event?

Comment: sorry, should have explained better... in the main frame i'm using setInterval. So this obviously allows a callback 'in'. So what is happening is the web worker callbacks are firing at this opportunity and then delaying the code that fires at the next setInterval timing... thus throwing the interval out of whack...

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve issue at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, after messing around with this for a while, i've realised what i thought was my problem is not actually my problem! what's actually happening is that when my web worker's finish this actually slows down my code... and given that i'm running an animation in the main frame this is seen as a stutter when each worker finishes! If I keep the worker going in the background with random tasks then this doesn't happen :-/  Very confusing??

Comment: Have you read the document at previous link?

Comment: to post some code?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what issue is with the code that you have tried